# Android achartengine : bar chart - bars appear upside down

Tags: android, achartengine

Am trying out to plot some values using achartengine in an Android App. The values in y axis are usually negative. This is how the bar chart appears

[image]

But I want it to appear from the bottom i.e. I want each bar to start from -100, instead of the current 0. How do I do this? Please help.

Comment: can someone please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you build a range bar chart instead of the current bar chart. Another suggestion is to use `renderer.setBarWidth(widthInPixels)` in order to set the width of the bars. This method works best when you have only one item per series.

Comment: Thanks Dan! I finally ended up using a LineChart with a very high line width, which simulated a bar-like appearance!